# snd_ctl_open failed. Invalid argument

Tags: audio, arm, debian, alsa

I am developing an application working with sound on a [board](https://www.olimex.com/wiki/A20-OLinuXino-LIME2) embedding an ARM architecture, on which a Debian distribution is present.

When I try to open the USB ([sound card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016CU2PEU)) plugged to the board, I do the following:

```
    while(1){

    if((err = snd_card_next(&card_num))<0){
        cout << "Can't get next card number" << endl;
        break;
    }
    if(card_num<0) break;

    snd_ctl_t *cardHandle;
    char   str[64];
        sprintf(str, "hw:%i", card_num);

    if ((err = snd_ctl_open(&cardHandle, str, 0)) < 0){
        cout << "Can't open card " << card_num << " , error = " << snd_strerror(err) << endl;
        continue;
    }

    snd_ctl_card_info_t *cardInfo;
        // We need to get a snd_ctl_card_info_t. Just alloc it on the stack
        snd_ctl_card_info_alloca(&cardInfo);

    if ((err = snd_ctl_card_info(cardHandle, cardInfo)) < 0){
        cout << "Can't get info for card " << card_num << endl;
        continue;
    }

        const char *mixer_name = snd_ctl_card_info_get_mixername(cardInfo);


    cout << "Card num " << card_num << " , name = " << snd_ctl_card_info_get_name(cardInfo) << " , mixer = " << mixer_name << endl;
    if(strcmp(mixer_name,"") > 0) {
        current_card_selected = card_num;
    }
    snd_ctl_close(cardHandle);
}
```

But the operation fails, and I get:

"Can't open Card 0, error = Invalid Argument"

"Can't open Card 1, error = Invalid Argument" (This is the USB sound card).

My idea is that the str[64] passed is wrongly defined as "hw:0,0" or "hw:1,0" ; but I don't know which alsa configuration file to look at and change.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 Intel x86_64 laptop everything works fine.

Any hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you verify that the sound card is present?  `aplay -l` or `cat /proc/asound/cards`.  There is a large library to match the names.  I suggest you use `int snd_card_get_name(int card, char **name)` and use a copy of this.

Comment: By using 'int snd_card_next(int *card)' and 'int snd_card_get_name(int card, char **name)' it works just fine.